# Popup div, fixed but scrollable when too big

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a div that pops up on a fixed position from the top of the viewport, wherever you are on the page. But, when this div has a lot of content, the page doesn't scroll.

So: first the div is out of view, when button is clicked it slides into view. And then you can scroll that div. But the whole page has to scroll, not just inside that div.

It works when I use 'position: absolute', but then it pops up from the top of the body instead of the viewport.

Here's the simple CSS to start with:

```
div.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 50px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uPmb4/

I hope you get the idea what I'm trying to arrange, but maybe my approach isn't the best way to begin with.

Comment: Make it `position:absolute`then move it to right position with javascript on popup. You can get current slider position with JQuery: `$(window).scrollTop()` function.

Answer (score 4):

So if there is too much content in the red box, you want both the red box and the page to scroll separately?

How about this:

```
div.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    // I assume you want the red box to always be 50px from the top
    // no matter the viewport height?
    // This will make sure the bottom edge is at the bottom of the viewport
    // However, you shouldn't use calc if you need to support older browsers.
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    // Make sure it scrolls if too much content
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: red;
    // No need for margin-top
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNsk2/1/)**

Comment: No, the red box has to make the page scroll, not an inside scroll bar. It sounds so easy, but I'm not getting there.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing "min-height" for "height", and adding "overflow:auto" seems to work:

```
div.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 50px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: The min-height is needed when there's not enough content to fill the overlay. And overflow:auto adds a scroll bar inside the overlay. It's the page that needs to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

min-height: 100%; and margin-top: 50px; are creating the problem. 50px of the content disappear beneath the current viewport. Place a wrapper inside the div.overlay and give that a margin-top: 50px;

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle, but still when the overlay has overflow, you cannot scroll it (see menu item 3). [Update here](http://jsfiddle.net/uPmb4/26/)

Answer (score 0):

Set all the overlay divs to have the `movedown` class and do not use top: 100% in the overlay. Then if you add `overflow-y: auto` you're all set.

```
div.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uPmb4/10/

Comment: Indeed, but the scrollbar is inside the overlay, and I want it on the whole page. The new Wikipedia Media Viewer is a good example: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Media_Viewer#mediaviewer/File:Media_Viewer_Desktop_-_Large_Image_Opaque_Info.png)

Comment: Do you need multiple different overlays (like your example with 3 links) or just one?

Comment: The wikipedia media viewer does things the same way - the whole page is scrolling the top part is the one that has a fixed position and the overlay scrolls over the top. If any of the text within that overlay overflows then it will need a scrollbar too.

Comment: Every menu item opens a new layer, so different ones. How do I get that overlay makes the page scroll, not just inside that div? Seen menu item 03 in the JSFiddle.